# Check if any property of object has null value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have following array of objects `data`, that has multiple properties, some of them can have null value.

[image]

I want to filter through this array of objects and remove every object that has property of null value.
So far I have tried this code, but with no luck:

```
const noNull = data.filter((doc) => { return Object.values(doc).some(prop => { if (prop !== null) return doc; } )});
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Updated to keep items which do not have a null value

```
const noNull = obj.filter((doc) => { return Object.values(doc).every(prop => prop !== null)})
```

`.some()` and `.every()` expect **boolean** return value

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#:%7E:text=Description,Otherwise%2C%20some()%20returns%20false%20.)